# active directory issues with server change

Tags: centos, active-directory

The office I began to do some IT work in had a 6 year old Dell server running Windows Server 2008. The server had all sorts of hardware issues - long story short one of the CPU's failed and the server's dead now.

We bought a new server and are moving the OS to CentOS because Linux is a much more familiar environment and is easier to administrate for the current staff (it is a small office and there are only about 30 computers at most at any time on the network).

I want to essentially entirely wipe all AD records so that I can start over and build up a new system entirely. Would a AD tool be useful at all if I just disabled everything? At that point, how would I gain administrative access to the computer since I have no records of what the previous IT people did?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. If the old AD server is dead and you're replacing it with Linux, then what AD records would still exist? What is there to disable?

Comment: I have no idea, but for some reason when I log into the machines it's still searching for the old network drives, and the software that used to be on the server - I'm assuming this is AD?

Comment: They're probably joined to a domain. There was only one AD server?

Comment: Network drives *could* have been mapped via AD policy, or they were mapped as mapped drives on the client.

Comment: I believe after reading the below answer that I need to disjoin them from the domain - I'm just a student and I bought a Active Directory book that I'm going to read, I clearly need to understand this topic better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disjoin the clients from the domain (put them in workgroup mode), you'll need to remove any static drive mappings that exist (from within Windows Explorer), you'll need to configure the clients with new DNS server settings, and you'll need to migrate each user's profile from their domain profile to their new profile.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to give this a shot tomorrow morning, will report back

Comment: Looking forward to hearing back...

Comment: Glad to help...